# How to achieve Google+ Public Profile page like navigation header animation

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, google-plus

[image][image]

I had scenario in which i want google+ profile Page like header animation, in which there's no navigation bar but when we scroll up and down navigation and status bar are presented animatedly.Can anybody help me out in this.

Comment: Can anybody provide me some better hint or source code, it would be great help.

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy:

```
float lastOffset;

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{        

    float offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;


    if ( offset > lastOffset ) {

       [self hideNavigationBar];
    } else  {

        [self showNavigationBar];
    }
}
- (void)hideNavigationBar
{



    CALayer *layer = self.viewParent.navigationController.navigationBar.layer;


    CGPoint navBarDefaultPosition = CGPointMake((int)self.view.frame.size.width/2.0f,42);


    if (layer.position.x == navBarDefaultPosition.x &&
        layer.position.y == navBarDefaultPosition.y && self.data.count > 0) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            layer.position = CGPointMake(layer.position.x,
                                         -self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.
                                         size.height);

        }];
    }  
}

-(void)showNavigationBar
{

    CALayer *layer = self.viewParent.navigationController.navigationBar.layer;

    CGPoint navBarDefaultPosition = CGPointMake((int)self.view.frame.size.width/2.0f,42);

    if ( layer.position.y != navBarDefaultPosition.x ) { 

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
            layer.position = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,42);



        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Martin can you add a demo project on git an provide me the link for that.

Comment: This is actually not pushing the Section header down but the navigation bar is coming over section header of table view.